# Could not find server 'dbo' in sys.servers.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, syntax-error

I am having problems with my SQL over this issue, I have done select * from sys.servers to check that my server is listed and it is.

I have also done the query select name from sys.servers and my server name is listed.

Here is my code

```
    declare @Source_Database_Name AS varchar(255) = 'dbo.Production2'
declare @Destination_Database_Name AS varchar(255) = 'c365online_script1'

declare @Company_Id AS int = 1 --declare a companyid 

CREATE TABLE #CompanyID1 (ID bigint)

INSERT INTO #CompanyID1(ID)
VALUES('1')

--FIRST CURSOR LOOP THROUGH THIS TABLE
CREATE TABLE #TableList (
processorder int,
tablename NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #TableList (processorder, tablename )
VALUES
(1, 'tCompany');

DECLARE @firstLoop BIT
--SET @firstLoop = true
DECLARE @Counter INT  -- counting variable

----------- Cursor specific code starts here ------------
-- company cursor
declare copyCompanyDataCursor CURSOR fast_forward FOR
SELECT ID from #CompanyID1;

open copyCompanyDataCursor
fetch next from copyCompanyDataCursor into @Company_Id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        declare @processorder int;
        declare @tablename varchar(500);
        -- table cursor

        declare copyTableDataCursor CURSOR fast_forward FOR
        SELECT processorder,tablename from #TableList order by processorder;

        open copyTableDataCursor
        fetch next from copyTableDataCursor into @processorder, @tablename;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [c365online_script1].[dbo].[tCompany] ON

            -- Does the table have a companyID column? if statement checking for company id
            IF EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM Production2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE COLUMN_NAME='CompanyID' and TABLE_NAME='tProperty')
                    BEGIN
                    declare @debug varchar(max)
                          EXEC('INSERT INTO ' + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' WHERE ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + '.CompanyID = ' + @Company_Id )
                    END
                            ELSE
                    BEGIN 
                            Print 'No'
                    END 
            -- if yes then copy data based on companyID in cursor



            -- if no check if this is the first time through company loop and copy all data
            -- if @firstloop company exists look at information schema

                    -- insert into c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany(selec
    EXEC('INSERT INTO ' + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename )

                    -- company logic


        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [c365online_script1].[dbo].[tCompany] OFF

            FETCH NEXT FROM copyTableDataCursor into @processorder,@tablename;
        END

        close copyTableDataCursor;

        Deallocate copyTableDataCursor;

--INSERT INTO c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany
--SELECT *
--FROM production2.tCompany
--WHERE ISNULL(CompanyID, 0) = 0  -- copy all data where id is equal to zero
--@Destination_Database_Name

--      
        --EXEC(INSERT  + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' WHERE ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + '.CompanyID = ' + @Company_Id + ')')     
        --SET @firstLoop = false;
        FETCH NEXT FROM copyCompanyDataCursor into @Company_Id;
    END

CLOSE copyCompanyDataCursor;
DEALLOCATE copyCompanyDataCursor;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your code is

```
declare @Source_Database_Name AS varchar(255) = 'dbo.Production2'
```

Is your database *actually* called `dbo.Production2`?

If so you will need square brackets when using that name. i.e. reference it as `[dbo.Production2]`

That is quite a confusing database name `dbo` is also the default schema. So generally you expect to see it appear *after* the database name. Not before.

Comment: Yes my database name is Production2 when i did [dbo.Production2] SQL says invalid column name

Comment: @user2520671 - you've not answered the question Martin asked. Martin asked if your database is called `dbo.Production2` - you've answered that "yes, it is called `Production2`" - do you not realise that those two strings of characters are not the same?

Comment: The name of the database is just Production2

Comment: @user2520671 - So why are you assigning the value `dbo.Production2`? Do you actually have a linked server called "dbo"? (Again would be confusing!)

Comment: So if you change that to `declare @Source_Database_Name AS varchar(255) = 'Production2'` then problem solved?